# Overriding transmogrifier:registerConfig without using overrides.zcml

Tags: plone, zope, transmogrifier, zcml

I am using quintagroup.transmogrifier and I'd like to provide my on 'import.cfg' pipeline. Normally, I would put something like this in overrides.zcml:

```
<include package="collective.transmogrifier" file="meta.zcml" />
<transmogrifier:registerConfig
    name="import"
    title="Import pipeline configuration"
    description="My custom import pipeline."
    configuration="import.cfg"
    />
```

Several people pointed out that using overrides.zcml is not recommended. Moreover, I am having great troubles loading overrides.zcml in tests -- I get duplicate configuration errors and such. So my question is how do I achieve my task (of providing my own pipeline) without using overrides.zcml?

Comment: Why do you need to use `overrides.zcml` in the first place? Why not just register this in `configure.zcml`? Don't tell me Quintagroup requires you to override this, that'd be.. shall we say.. shortsighted?

Comment: AFAIU their code, yes, you need to override it as they look for an "import" pipeline and I didn't see anywhere that I could tell q.transmogrifier to use a different pipeline name for importing.

Comment: /me buries his head in his hands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the reason behind the deprecation of `overrides.zcml` results from the fact that some black magic is done in order to load them (which you have to replicate in your `p.a.testing` setup), which is probably done by the zope server in its startup routine.

Sadly, I am not aware of anything better than going directly on the configuration_registry (located in `collective.transmogrifier.transmogrifier`, and it's a global). If you call `registerConfig` directly you should be able to override it, but it's dirtier than using `overrides.zcml`.

An alternative might be looking into `zope.configuration` to see if you can do the override via code...

Comment: In the end what I did was to clear() the transmogrifier configuration_registry, just before I loaded the overrides.zcml in my test layer setup. Thanks for the tip!